# I am trying to compare results of normal distribution with t distribution for unknown df value

Tags: r, distribution, normal-distribution

I have to compare results of a normal quantile (.975 for eg) with various df values in t distributions till it gives same results as the normal distribution's same quantile. 
eg; find minimum df value for .975 quantile of t distribution to result in same value as .975 quantile of normal distribution upto 2 decimal places.(don't necessarily need r code for this, although it would help for next part of assignment.)

need an r code that can do the same as above but with any quantile and any number of decimal places.

I tried tackling with the .975 version first but with no luck, a and b are variables with qnorm and qt results:

```
a <- round(qnorm(.975,0,1),2)
a

df <- c(1:1000)
b <- round(qt(.975,df),2)
b

for (i in 1:length(df)) {
    if (round(qt(.975,df[i]),2)==round(qnorm(.975,0,1),2)) {
    df[i]
    }
}
```

Tried it in as simple as if a==b, then return df value for i, and got error the condition has length >1 and only the first element will be used, the above code on the other hand doens;t give any errors or result.

Comment: you can generate samples without a loop: `qts = qt(.975, 1:1000) ; 
qn = qnorm(.975, 0, 1)`. And then compare them: `round(qts,2) - round(qn,2)`. You can use this last bit to pull out the dof'd where the diff is zero.

Comment: literally just had this thought 10 min ago before checking for answers. Thank you, will try this solution. What about the second bit? how can I build a code where we can compare any quantile of the 2 distribution regardless of the rounding? Functions, perhaps?

Comment: Heena, yes a function is the way to go. For example, it could take two arguments, one for the quantile, and one for the digits to round to. So to start use `HennaFun <- function(quant, dig){ ... }`, where you fill in the `...`? Leave a comment if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks! also, how do I not limit the df values? I tried 1:Inf and it gave me the error "the result would be too long a  vector". Whats the max amount I can apply to df variable?

Comment: Hi, Henna. I dont know if what is the largest dof you could use -- but you do need to limit it and not to Inf ;). Just add it as a third function argument.

Comment: I'm probably still too new to r. so regarding round(qts,2) - round(qn,2); how do I just show the final result? Like i created a table to show all values with the difference and the corresponding df values in order so I can answer my question by looking at the table, but how do I code this to show the final answer itself? I tried filtering the table to get diff == 0 ( and also tried 0.00) but just keep getting errors. same issue with subsetting as well. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi Heena ; quick n dirty function to get you started: 
`heena <- function(qt, rnd, dof){;
    qts = qt(qt, df=seq_len(dof));  
    qn = qnorm(qt, 0, 1) ;
    dif = round(qts, rnd) - round(qn,rnd);
    idx = which(dif==0)[1];
    if(is.na(idx)) warning("you need to increase the dof") ;
    return(idx);
}`
run `heena(0.975, 3, 1000)` should give warning, then try `heena(0.975, 3, 5000)` (ps each `;`  means code goes on a new line)

Comment: ... although it may be worth using `qt(qt, df=dof)`, and using for example, `heena(0.975, 3, 3000:5000)` to save using all the earlier values which are known not to be required. ps you could use ` while` loop to save creating a big long vector

Comment: Thanks a ton! this worked like magic. (Which) function is what I was looking for. Not sure why filter didn't work though. Thanks for all your help.:)